# Getting an error while trying to input arbitrary number of grouping variables and summary variables using tidy dots in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to use tidy dots to build a function that I can use to summarize the data based on the requirement. I need to group by variables using different metrics based on the requirement.

Sample Data:

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(Branch = c("MDU", "KPA", "OMR", "TVM", "KPA", 
"MDU", "MDU", "MDB", "MDU", "OMR", "MDU", "AMB", "OMR", "OMR", 
"GDY", "TVM", "KLM", "EKM", "MDU", "TVM", "KPA", "TVM", "GDY", 
"EKM", "TVM", "KLM", "TVM", "TVM", "AMB", "TVM"), InvoiceDate = structure(c(18475, 
18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 
18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 
18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 18475, 
18475, 18475), class = "Date"), LabourRev = c(1093, 300, 1, 2637.86, 
255, 624, 634.75, 3645, 570, 5250, 900, 1500, 423, 1614, 999, 
1140, 2914, 1640, 0, 2574, 255, 1046, 1999, 2637, 1355, 1144, 
0, 1355, 1999, 3240.5), PartsRev = c(1111.98, 990, 0, 16555.64, 
178, 2857.5, 31.74, 3265.03, 28.5, 1942.18, 45, 75, 21.15, 441.71, 
49.95, 3919.5, 10652.72, 4877.58, 0, 16616.53, 1108.11, 1000.49, 
99.95, 2889.68, 0, 3127.34, 0, 0, 99.95, 3618.73), TotalAmt = c(2204.98, 
1290, 1, 19193.5, 433, 3481.5, 666.49, 6910.03, 598.5, 7192.18, 
945, 1575, 444.15, 2055.71, 1048.95, 5059.5, 13566.72, 6517.58, 
0, 19190.53, 1363.11, 2046.49, 2098.95, 5526.68, 1355, 4271.34, 
0, 1355, 2098.95, 6859.23)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

structure:

```
> str(d)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   30 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Branch     : chr  "MDU" "KPA" "OMR" "TVM" ...
 $ InvoiceDate: Date, format: "2020-08-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-08-01" ...
 $ LabourRev  : num  1093 300 1 2638 255 ...
 $ PartsRev   : num  1112 990 0 16556 178 ...
 $ TotalAmt   : num  2205 1290 1 19194 433 ...
```

For example, I may group by just Branch or month of Invoice Date or by both.

I tried writing the below function for which I am getting the error as mentioned below:

```
mult_grouping <- function(df, ..., ...){
   grping_vars <- enquos(..., .named = 1)
   summary_vars <- enquos(..., .named = 1)
    
   smry_sum <- map(summary_vars, function(var){
      expr(sum(!!var, na.rm = 1))
   })
    
   names(smry_sum) <- paste0('sum_',names(smry_sum))
    
   df %>% 
     group_by(!!!grping_vars) %>% 
     summarise(!!!smry_sum, Counts = n())
}
```

> Error: repeated formal argument '...' on line 1

Are we supposed to use tidy dots just once in a function? Could someone let me know how to correct the code.

Comment: How do you want to pass your inputs columns. With quotes or without quotes? `mult_grouping <- function(d, c("col1", "col3", "col2")` Or `mult_grouping <- function(d, c(col1, col3, col2)`

Comment: I guess either will do, just need the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need complicated non-standard evaluation if you can pass column names as string, `across` handles string column names.

```
library(dplyr)

mult_grouping <- function(df, group_vars, summary_vars) {
  
  df %>%
    mutate(InvoiceDate = lubridate::month(InvoiceDate)) %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(group_vars))) %>%
    summarise(across(all_of(summary_vars), sum), 
              Counts = n())
}
```

1. Single group column, single value column

```
d %>% mult_grouping("Branch", "LabourRev")

# Branch LabourRev Counts
#  <chr>      <dbl>  <int>
#1 AMB        3499       2
#2 EKM        4277       2
#3 GDY        2998       2
#4 KLM        4058       2
#5 KPA         810       3
#6 MDB        3645       1
#7 MDU        3822.      6
#8 OMR        7288       4
#9 TVM       13348.      8
```

2. Multiple group column single value columns.

```
d %>% mult_grouping(c("Branch", "InvoiceDate"), "LabourRev")

# Branch InvoiceDate LabourRev Counts
#  <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>  <int>
#1 AMB              8     3499       2
#2 EKM              8     4277       2
#3 GDY              8     2998       2
#4 KLM              8     4058       2
#5 KPA              8      810       3
#6 MDB              8     3645       1
#7 MDU              8     3822.      6
#8 OMR              8     7288       4
#9 TVM              8    13348.      8
```

3. Multiple group column, multiple value column

```
d %>% mult_grouping(c("Branch", "InvoiceDate"), c("LabourRev", "PartsRev"))

#  Branch InvoiceDate LabourRev PartsRev Counts
#  <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>
#1 AMB              8     3499      175.      2
#2 EKM              8     4277     7767.      2
#3 GDY              8     2998      150.      2
#4 KLM              8     4058    13780.      2
#5 KPA              8      810     2276.      3
#6 MDB              8     3645     3265.      1
#7 MDU              8     3822.    4075.      6
#8 OMR              8     7288     2405.      4
#9 TVM              8    13348.   41711.      8
```

---

To have a flexible date column we can pass it as a separate argument in the function.

```
mult_grouping <- function(df, group_vars, summary_vars, date_cols = NULL) {
  if(is.null(date_cols)) {
  df %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(group_vars))) %>%
    summarise(across(all_of(summary_vars), sum), 
              Counts = n())
  } else {
    df %>%
      mutate(date_col = lubridate::month(.data[[date_cols]])) %>%
      group_by(across(c(all_of(group_vars), date_col))) %>%
      summarise(across(all_of(summary_vars), sum), 
                Counts = n())
  }
}
```

and call them as :

```
d %>% mult_grouping("Branch", "LabourRev")

d %>% mult_grouping("Branch", c("LabourRev", "PartsRev"))

d %>% mult_grouping("Branch", c("LabourRev", "PartsRev"), "InvoiceDate")
```

Comment: Ronak, I need to group by month(InvoiceData) and not just InvoiceDate.

Comment: With this data yes, but aren't we hardcoding the column name using "mutate(InvoiceDate = lubridate::month(InvoiceDate)) ". The Date column names are different on different data sources that I'd work on. I can rename the column name each time I use the function or can add temporary "Month" column in the dataframe, but is there a way I can use the function as is.

Comment: So how do you know which is the date column and which is the grouping column? Meaning in this dataset how will you know you have to group by "Branch" and take month of "InvoiceDate" if we can't identify them by name?

Comment: I know the names of the columns by which I need to group by, I was talking about different datasets. For ex.this dataset deals with revenues, other dataset deals with customer inflow, another deals with product delivery etc, so the metrics and date columns are different in each dataset. So, If we hard code InvoiceDate as above, we need need to change the column name when we use this function for above dataset. It's fine to change the column name, but just wondered if it's possible without hard coding any column names.